# About nginx configure on Docker

Tags: docker, nginx

I am new to Docker and I have a server with Debian 9 system, and its IP is 104.167.123.123, and I installed an web application via Docker on it, the port is 3001, and I can visit the application via `http://127.0.0.1:3001` and `http://104.167.123.123:3001`, and I also installed Nginx via Docker on this server, the `default.conf` is following

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 500;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-PORT $remote_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

My questions are

1. How to make both IP access and IP:port access return 500, now IP access return 500, but ip:port is not, e.g. `104.167.123.123:3001`?
2. In `default.conf`, if `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;` the application cannot be accessed through the domain name, but if change to `proxy_pass http://104.167.123.123:3001;`, it can be accessed through the domain name, Why?

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: How you run your docker containers with app and nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make both IP access and IP:port access return 500, now IP
>   access return 500, but ip:port is not, e.g. 104.167.123.123:3001?

When you hit `IP` only the request sent to Nginx so Nginx returns 500 as you mentioned in the config, but when you try to access `104.167.123.123:3001` this request not route from Nginx but hit your backend server directly.

> In default.conf, if proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001; the application
>   cannot be accessed through the domain name, but if change to
>   proxy_pass http://104.167.123.123:3001;, it can be accessed through
>   the domain name, Why?

You are running Nginx inside docker, so `127.0.0.1:3000` mean localhost of Nginx container not backend container. while using  `http://104.167.123.123:3001;` this, nginx able to route this request to backend server.

You can solve the issue by doing following

- use docker-compose and do not expose port from the backend application so your backend service will not bot accessible by `IP:PORT`.
- use backend service name in nginx config instead of public ip of the container so you will not need to add public ip in the config or `localhost:3000`

for example

```
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://web:3000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-PORT $remote_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

docker-compose

```
web:
  image:nodejs
  command: node app.js
nginx:
  image:nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  depends_on:
    - web
```

Comment: Appending question: I had installed nginx via Docker, and I installed my web application via Docker by `docker run -d --name web webapplication`, and I changed `proxy_pass` to `http://web:3000`, I still can't hit this web application through domain name. How do I fix the above requirements on the premise that nginx has been installed? Thank you.

Comment: but to use docker-compose that do care of networking, but you can link to access service by name `docker run -it -p 80:80 --link web:web nginx` https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Comment: The above means how to bind a new application to an nginx that is already installed and running via Docker. The nginx controls some web applications, not only this one.

Comment: you can bind any application like the above, for long term use docker-compose, for app2 you can run `docker run -it -p 80:80 --link web:web --link app2:app2 nginx` you can refere app2 in nginx config like `app2:3001` etc

Comment: awsome, glad work for you, for long term use docker-compose.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again, if I used `docker-compose up -d` to started two containers (nginx and mywebapp), and I don't want to write them in one docker compose file, how can I link them? I found that `depends_on` doesn't work here.

Comment: then you can use pre created network in both docker-compse. but any reason not to use single compose file?

Comment: I have two webapps, and there is no relationship between them, but they all need nginx as proxy, so I wrote three docker compose files(webapp1, webapp2, nginx), but I don't know how to associate them in nginx compose file, it seems that I can't use `depend_on`.

Comment: Please look at this question, and you will know what I want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495219/which-is-better-to-create-docker-compose-yml-file/59495404